# What is the best way to attach evenly spaced and sized strips to this vest?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to attach strips to the front of the vest like as shown. I have attempted to use the shrinkwrap tool both normally and in the projecting mode, however it became distorted and some parts of it were clipping into the skin itself.I am trying to get the stripps to have some depth to them.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the strips a lattice modifier where the lattice is only 2D (1 segment in Y axis). Then put the skin-wrap mod on the lattice instead of the strips. This should make the lattice deform according to the surface and transfer that deformation to the strips without flattening them